# Counting data in excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

Im trying to create 2 formulas in excel to count the number of times data has been inputted.

The following 2 cells will contain the number of departed and returned vehicles.

> T1 = Departed T2 = Returned

In my spreadsheet each line corresponds to a vehicle starting from **A5** and ending at **A54**. In each line i have a cell for departed time and returned time and i think i should use those cells for counting the vehicles. My first line's cells for departing and returning are **J5 and U5**, the next line would be **J6 & U6** etc...

How would i construct a formula in **T1 & T2** to count the number of cells that contain data?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your question now,  please add some sample data with desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following =COUNTIF functions into each cell where you want the data to show. This will count in sequence so long as its greater then 0. To change this to a text function replace *>0* with *

=COUNTIF(T5:T52,">0")

=COUNTIF(J5:J52,">0")

Answer (score -1):

In T1 type:

```
=countif(j5:j54,">0")
```

In T2 type:

```
=countif(u5:u54,">0")
```

Comment: This is really a correction to Exhausted's answer.  Since you don't yet have the rep to comment, you could propose the correction as an edit.  The intention is that each answer provide a solution that is substantially different from what's already been contributed.  That's likely why your answer attracted a downvote.